# How to dynamically select a range and delete it

Tags: vba, ms-word

this is my first post here!

I am new to Microsoft VBA, but I need to write some macros to quickly make the same changes to 200+ documents. I took the Udemy course on Word VBA but I am stuck trying to figure out how to address the following issues:

1. I need to select all content from beginning of doc up until the first occurrence of the string "following:" including the string itself - the issue is that for each doc, this string will always be in a different position and the portion I want to delete will vary in length. The only guarantee is that it will always be on the first page.
2. I need to do the same thing for the end of the document - I need to delete all content following the string "Affirmative Defenses" including the string  itself - again, this will always be in a different position and will not always be on the last page (unlike issue number 1)

I have written many variations by reading other questions/solutions with no luck. Below is my current version but it does not work.

```
Sub DeleteBegin()

    Dim findRng As Range
    Set findRng = ActiveDocument.Range
    Dim endPara As Long

    With findRng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "following."
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .Forward = True
        .Execute

        If .Found = True Then
            endPara = GetParaNum(findRng)
            findRng.Start = 0
            findRng.End = endPara
        End If

    Dim capRng As Range
    Set capRng = ActiveDocument.Range
    capRng.SetRange Start:=0, End:=endPara
    capRng.Select
    Selection.Delete

    End With
End Sub

Function GetParaNum(ByRef r As Object) As Integer
    Dim rPara As Object
    Dim CurPos As Long

    r.Select
    CurPos = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\startOfSel").Start
    Set rPara = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=CurPos)
    GetParaNum = rPara.Paragraphs.Count

End Function
```

Comment: Please explain does not work. You will be more likely to get an answer if you provide what you want to do, what you have tried, what has worked, what hasn't and any results.

Comment: SetRange works by character count, not paragraph count. After you call the GetParaNum function, the next 2 statements look like you're also trying to set the range, but you haven't included this in a SetRange command. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.setrange

Comment: @EdneyHolder thank you for your comment. With my original code, I would get object errors or it would run but nothing would happen. Upon second glance, it is certainly fraught with errors. I have not been able to yield any results, just errors or nothing changing. I believe I explain what I would like to do above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument
  Set Rng = .Range(0, 0)
  With .Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = "following."
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Format = False
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Execute
    End With
    If .Find.Found = True Then
      Rng.End = .Duplicate.End
      Rng.Delete
    End If
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = "Affirmative Defenses"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Format = False
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .MatchCase = True
      .Execute
    End With
    If .Find.Found = True Then
      Set Rng = .Duplicate
      Rng.End = ActiveDocument.Range.End
      Rng.Delete
    End If
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking a stab at this! When I run this code, there are no errors but nothing happens either. Seems to not take long, but the document remains unchanged. Perhaps because of `Set Rng = .Range(0,0)` The end might have to be extended? Of course, these are just guesses as I do not have a complete grasp of the language yet.

Comment: @JasmineMann The code works fine, though I did have to change the first 'find' expression (I initially had 'following:' instead of 'following.'). If the second part doesn't work, that's because the 'Affirmative Defenses' string you specified doesn't exist.

Comment: I didn't catch that! It works! Thank you so so much. You've helped resolve a long term headache.